# Navigation Drawer Activity with Map Fragment : getting crashed

Tags: android

Have used Navigation Drawer Activity (Provided by Android not Custom) and Map Fragment (Support Fragment) in same activity.
The app is working fine for OS version 5 and above.
But app get crashed for OS version less than 5 (Have checked on version 4.4, 4.2)

crash Log showing error at line `setContentView(R.layout.HomeActivity);`

Log:

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #16: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2338)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2390)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1321)
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5292)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:824)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:640)
     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #16: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:620)
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696)
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:256)
     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:109)
     at com.example.Activities.HomeActivity.onCreate(HomeActivity.java:140)
     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5264)
     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1088)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2302)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2390) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1321) 
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110) 
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5292) 
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:824) 
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:640) 
     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
 Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594)
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696) 
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755) 
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492) 
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397) 
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353) 
     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:256) 
     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:109) 
     at com.example.Activities.HomeActivity.onCreate(HomeActivity.java:140) 
     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5264) 
     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1088) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2302) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2390) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1321) 
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110) 
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
                   ...
```

Comment: Can you post your code?

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in first line, problem in your XML file in layout. Just check, maybe you use parameters, which supported only from Android 5 and higher. You have to remove or replace that parameters, to another.

If you use Android Studio, that line should be highlighted with some message. Read more about it -  [not supported elements](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Deprecated.html).

```
Binary XML file line #16
```